# Find a basis of a subset given an equation

Tags: linear-algebra

$W = \{(x_{1}, x_{2}, x_{3})\in $R$^3: \frac{x_{1}}{3} = \frac{x_{2}}{4} = \frac{x_{3}}{2}\}$

Find a basis for $W$

I need help. I don't know how to do this.

Comment: To start- You should list what you have tried. Do you know what a basis is? What is the definition of a basis? If you know these things then The solution follows directly from David's answer.

Comment: I know that a basis is something which spans the set and is linearly independant. The thing is, I'm not looking for an answer. I don't know how to do it and am looking to see if someone can explain it to me.

Comment: That is good! In David's solution he shows that every element of $W$ can be written in the form $(3\lambda, 4\lambda, 2\lambda)$ for some $\lambda$. Indeed, if $(x_1,x_2,x_3)\in W$ then setting $\lambda=x_1/3 (=x_2/4=x_3/2)$ we get $(x_1,x_2,x_3)=(\lambda 3,\lambda 4,\lambda 2)=\lambda(3,4,2)$. This means that every element in $W$ is just some multiple of $(3,4,2)$ and so $(3,4,2)$ spans $W$! Now the linearly independent condition is meaningless here since we only have one nonzer vector, so $\{(3,4,2)\}$ is a basis of $W$. Does that help?

Comment: OK so I get the explanation. Thanks for that! But it's just the algebra that was a bit weird for me. But as I was writing this comment, I just figured it out. So simple and I can't believe I missed it.

Comment: Great! You are welcome. Thanks for posting the problem

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Hint**.  Write
$$\frac{x_1}{3}=\frac{x_2}{4}=\frac{x_3}{2}=\lambda\ .$$
Then your set is
$$W=\{\,(3\lambda,4\lambda,2\lambda)\mid \lambda\in{\Bbb F}\,\}\ .$$